# Breeze - run metadata only once

Tags: breeze

I have three query against the server. Before each query breeze run "Metadata". Is there a way to run this function only once? I think there is no need for it, because the model hasn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, the only reason that i can think that can make breeze to ask for metadata in each query is because you are not reusing the manager and you are creating a new manager for each query.

If that is the reason, you can see this section of the documentation where is explained how to share a single entity manager:

http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/share-entitymanager

Comment: No i defined my manager in my masterViewModel. "var query1 ...", "masterViewModel.manager.executeQuery(query1)", "var query2 ..." , "masterViewModel.manager.exeut..." , "var query3" ..."

breeze run metadata for all three queries